# Why the assignment of an object is lost when I utilize free()?

Tags: delphi, object, lazarus, freepascal

I have a problem. For example, when I try get an object from a function or assign.

```
//Global.-
MyObject:= TMyObject.Create();  
//Local assign.-
myObj:= MyObject;
```

In the above case if I try this:

```
//Global variable.-
MyObject:= TMyObject.Create();
MyObject.MyData:= 'Salam world';  
//Local variable.-
myObj:= MyObject;
MyObject.Free();
...
ShowMessage(myObj.MyData); //Don't show the data.-
```

Show an access violation for this:

```
//Global variable.-
MyObject:= TMyObject.Create();
MyObject.MyData:= 'Salam world';
...
//Local variable.-
myObj:= TMyObject.Create();
myObj:= MyObject;
..
MyObject.Free();
...
ShowMessage(myObj.MyData);
```

What I need is to free the global variable before the local variable. But I could keep the copy of the data in the allocation.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: when you do this `myObj:= MyObject`, both variables became the same object. So, when you calling `MyObject.Free()` after that - the `myObj` variable also is freed. So, I can't understand, why you trying to free `MyObject` object, if you want to use it's data further in the code?

Comment: Why do you need two variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't free variable you can only free/destroy object.

So when in your code you call

```
MyObject.Free();
```

You are actually destroying the object that `MyObject` variable reference/pints to. And that is the same object that your myObj variable reference/points to.

And the reason why they both point to the same object is that when you called

```
myObj:= MyObject;
```

you simply copied the data used by your program to reference to that object from mObj variable into MyObject variable.

You see in Delphi/Object Pascal there are two types of variables. Referenced and Non-referenced variables.

Non-referenced variables are simple variables like Integers for instance. They directly point to the memory location containing their data. And their size is exactly the same as the size of the memory block that they point to.

Referenced variables which are all variables referencing classes, interfaces, or strings are different. Instead of pointing directly to the memory block containing the object they instead point to special reference to that object (instance). That reference then actually contains information of where in memory does that object resides and how big it is.

Main advantage of referenced variables is that you can have multiple referenced variables all referencing to the same object. That especially comes useful when you have different naming of these variables in different parts of code.

But the main disadvantage of them is that you need to have proper mechanism in order to make sure that the memory that contains the object they reference to is freed up at the right time. That is why you need to call `MyObject.Free` or `MyObject.Destroy` in order for that memory to be freed.

Now in case of using advanced referencing you don't need to call the objects destructor yourself since ARC contains its own mechanism to figure out when certain object is no longer required and can be freed (reference count reaches zero).

In your question you state that you want your global variable not to point to your object any more but still have your local variable point to that object.

I guess there are two possible reasons for this:

In first you may want your global object to reference to another object while retaining reference to the old object in local scope. To do so you can simply assign new object reference to your global object variable

```
MyGlobalObject := SomeNewObject;
```

or

```
MyGlobalObject := TSomeObject.Create;
```

in second you may want that your global object variable no longer references any valid object. In this case you only need to set it to special `nil` state

```
MyGlobalObject := nil;
```

Any way in either case be sure that before you change your global object variable that you have at least one other variable referencing to that object. Why?

Because if you change your last variable pointing to some object to point to some other object or none at all you lose the ability to interact and free that initial objects memory. In programming terminology such scenarios are called memory leaks.

Comment: "in Delphi/Object Pascal there are two types of variables. Referenced and Non-referenced variables." Actually it should say: "in Delphi/Object Pascal there are reference types and value types"

Comment: @StefanGlienke Strictly following official terminology yes. But strictly replacing what I have said with what you are suggesting would probably confuse the OP even more. Especially if he does not understand the basic definition of variable and how variable type affects the way how data is assigned to it. So I have decided to skip using official terminology and use descriptive terminology instead in order to help OP understand what I'm trying to tell him. And based on the fact that OP marked my answer as correct one even thou he previously marked Ken White's one as correct I guess I succeeded.

Answer (score 4):

When you perform the assignment the way you are, you're not creating a copy of the object; you're merely making two variables reference the same object. Freeing that object means that the second variable is pointing to the object you've free'd.

```
//Global variable.-
MyObject:= TMyObject.Create();
MyObject.MyData:= 'Salam world';
```

The next line does not make a second copy of the object. It just makes `myObj` also point to `MyObject`.

```
//Local variable.-
myObj:= MyObject;
```

You can see this yourself using the following code:

```
MyObject := TMyObject.Create;
MyObject.MyData := 'Some text';
ShowMessage(MyObject.MyData);      // Shows 'Some text'

myObj := MyObject;
// Change local variable property value
myObj.MyData := 'Different text';
// Display global variable property value
ShowMessage(MyObject.MyData);     // Shows 'Different text'
```

This line frees `MyObject`, meaning that `myObj` now references the object you just freed, since it merely points to the content of `MyObject`.

```
MyObject.Free();
```

If you want to make a copy, use `Assign` instead.

```
myObj := TMyObject.Create;
myObj.Assign(MyObject);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that in your own classes you should implement Assign method yourself, default implementation in TPersistent calls AssignTo of source, which is probably not implemented also, so you end up with exception.